# Dynamic name to underscore js template is causing problems

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have this code in backbone.js:

```
render: function(type) {
  var html = _.template($('#book-page-template-type-'+type).html(), this.model.toJSON());
  this.$el.html(html); 
  return this;
}
```

Were the type dynamically creates different versions of a web form template. That works great and I can render the view successfully.

**But** when I am trying to save changes made in the view to the server:

```
  save: function(){
  var text = this.$("#page-title").val();
  var content = this.$("#page-content").val();
  this.model.set({"title":text,"content":content});
  this.model.save();
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #book-page-template-type-[object Object]

Which obviously refers to the template name. (BTW the error is coming from jQuery).

Why is that happening ?

Comment: Is your render method bound to the `change` event of your view? I'm guessing that perhaps when you save the `change` event is triggered and the render method is being fired but type is the `event` parameter. Try logging out a *stringified* version of `type` in your render method.

Comment: @Jack Thank you very much, that was the problem. I will look for a way to fix that.